# how to view PostgreSQL database on windows 7?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I installed an application that uses a PostgreSQL database. When I installed the application it automatically installed PostgreSQL for me.

How can I view the raw PostgreSQL database rows?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **psql**, a command line tool which may already be installed with your code, or you can use pgAdmin if you prefer a gui tool.  Also many scripting languages, perl, python, etc. have libraries that allow easy access to the database.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pgAdmin, which might've been automatically installed when PostgreSQL was otherwise you can [download it for free](http://www.pgadmin.org/).  They've also got a [10 minute introductory video on using pgAdmin](http://www.enterprisedb.com/learning/videos/Create_Postgres_Database_pgAdmin.do)